# tikz-cd error: Single ampersand used with wrong catcode

Tags: tikz-cd

I'm trying to draw a diamond-shaped commutative diagram using the tikz-cd package. Below is my LaTeX source:

```
\documentclass{amsart} 

\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\[\begin{tikzcd} 
& A \arrow{dl}\arrow{dr} &\\
B \arrow{dr} & \arrow{dl} C\\
& D & 
\end{tikzcd}\]

\end{document}
```

When I compile this using pdflatex, I get the error:

```
Package pgfbasematrix Error: Single ampersand used with wrong catcode.
```

I've looked around on this site, in the documentation and online, and I've only seen this error arise before when using Beamer or trying to define a newcommand. Since I'm doing neither, I'm at a loss as to what's going on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You missed one ampersand on the 2nd line.

Also, as observed by @egreg and the OP, the last `&` in the 1st and 3rd lines are not necessary, and you should start only the 1st line with `{}`.

```
\documentclass{amsart} 

\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd} 
{}& A \arrow{dl}\arrow{dr} & \\
B \arrow{dr} &&  C\arrow{dl} \\
  & D  
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, thanks. I toyed with changing the number of ampersands to see if that was the problem, but missed using {}. Why is this not always necessary when beginning a line with &?

Comment: @AlexBecker, I don't why but sometimes we have to insert some characters with no effect, like `{}` to change the behavior of others. Maybe some expert could explain better.

Comment: It's necessary only to start the first line with `{}`; the trailing `&` are not needed. I don't really know why the first `&` must be preceded by something (even empty), but it surely has to do with TikZ internals (matrices are quite strange in how they use `&`).

Comment: @egreg, I'll edit the post and cite your note.

Comment: @Sigur I believe that the trailing & is not needed on the first line either. I just throw them in for bookkeeping.