# tikz-cd error: anything wrong with placing of ampersands?

Tags: tikz-cd

I'm trying to draw a triangle-shaped commutative diagram using the tikz-cd package. Here is my LaTeX source:

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd} 
{}& A \arrow{dl}\arrow{dr}& \\
B\arrow{r}   &&  C
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

I tried to follow the post of Sigur in [tikz-cd error: Single ampersand used with wrong catcode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117079/tikz-cd-error-single-ampersand-used-with-wrong-catcode#) but I still get the error message

```
! Package pgf Error: No shape named tikz@f@1-2-2 is known.
```

Playing with ampersands was of no help. (I can easily draw a commutative diagram of the form of a right triangle by placing A in the first column, but I don't see why I cannot use my above code to place A in the middle column and get an isosceles triangle.)

Comment: I believe you want `\arrow{rr}` in the bottom row (and no trailing `&` in the top row).

Comment: @egreg Sorry, didn't see your comment before I posted the answer. Do you want to answer instead?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Don't worry!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That error means that there is no node in the second cell on the second row, as there is no content there. To get around that you can add `{}` in that cell, or `[nodes in empty cells]` after `\begin{tikzcd}`.

That said, I presume you want the arrow to go all the way from B to C, so you want `\arrow{rr}`, not `\arrow{r}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd} 
{}& A \arrow{dl}\arrow{dr}& \\
B\arrow{r}   & {} &  C
\end{tikzcd}

\begin{tikzcd}[nodes in empty cells]
{}& A \arrow{dl}\arrow{dr}& \\
B\arrow{r}   &  &  C
\end{tikzcd}

\begin{tikzcd} 
{}& A \arrow{dl}\arrow{dr}& \\
B\arrow{rr}   &  &  C
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the nodes in empty cells, that's really nice. By the way, I've noticed that I can remove {} in the first line and the code runs on my computer with no errors. Why is that? I was expecting to get an error without it as I learned from the post that I've linked to my question.

Comment: @EPS I don't know why that was required before, but that question was written before version 3 of TikZ came out I believe, so probably something has changed in TikZ's handling of their `matrix` nodes.